# Validating Google Recaptcha 2 in Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, recaptcha

I was wondering something about Recaptcha validation.

I currently implemented the recaptcha in my form, but the recaptcha doesnt seem to prevent the submit handler of the form. So I assume I have to write my own specific code for it. However!...is this bot-safe? Cant bots just disable the recaptcha validation and still submit the form?

Please enlighten me,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to plug the recaptcha in a manner that it is required to have a successful test to submit the form. As you can see, on the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#site_verify_response) of Google, they will handle the challenge for the user (or bot) and send you a `success`, either `false` or `true`.
If it does not pass, do not allow them to submit the form. If they do disable the JS, they will not be able to submit it neither ofc.

And yeah, a recaptcha works well against bots, it's the goal of it. Some low recaptchas can be a bit too naive and data bots could detect some patterns and still succeed a submission but they are a few and you can still go for a score of `1` or `0.9`. It basically determines "how much are you human", `1` guarantees that it's really unlikely that it's a bot.

Why isn't the submission blocked in your case ? It's the thing that you need to investigate or post a question with it's content.

[This module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module) is aimed towards Nuxt, so it may help be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! A question to verify something. Cant bots modify my JS code in a way that the form will not require a success response? (I am still in the process of trying to understand what bots/hackers can and cannot do to my code, since JS does a lot client-side)

Comment: Bots should not have the ability to modify your frontend, if your app is secure, without any major security flaw like code injection, it should be fine. At the end of the day, if your app is "hacked" and your recaptcha is disabled, I guess it's not a big deal (compared to what could have happen to your database or alike). Backend code will always be more secure (even if prone to more vector of attacks too IMO) but you could always have a backend validation on top of your frontend one, to like double-check that the user have passed the recaptcha. PS: I'm not a security expert neither.